# strcpy with strings array

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm working with arrays, I've done passing strings array to functions and other bit banging with strings and ints arrays.

Now, I have a problem with `strcpy`, what I did and want to know:

1. It crashes with if I assign `strcpy(temp, str1[i]);` while `temp` is `char *temp`.
2. single string array `temp[100]`. However, I didn't figure out how to calculate the size of the `temp` to the string element of the array. I understood that I have to give 17 as the size of `temp` so fit the bytes from the string array.
   Like:
   `char *temp[17];` then, I can apply `strcpy(temp, str1[i]);`
   Where `*str1[] = {"sweepsweepsweepsweep"}` 20 chars. And crashes with size of 16.
3. I can't assign one member of stings array to another member.
   But I saw one code which do that.
4. Another thing that is why if I declared other empty string arrays `str2` & `str3`, they have the same values as `str1`? It's included at the end of the code example.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{      
    int m = 0, j = 1, n, i;
    char *str1[] = {"sweep", "forward"}, *str2[] = {}, *str3[] = {}, *temp;
    uint8_t cnt = sizeof(str1) / sizeof(str1[0]);

    if (strcmp(str1[m], str1[j]) > 0) {
        strcpy(temp, str1[m]);
        strcpy(str1[m], str1[j]);
        strcpy(str1[j], temp);
        printf("OK\n");
    } else {
        printf("NOPE\n");       
    }
    printf("The sorted string\n");
    for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
        puts(str1[i]);     
    printf("%d\n", strcmp(str1[0], str1[1]));
    printf("-----------------\n");

    printf("temp: %s\n", temp);
    printf("str2: %s\n", str2[0]);
    printf("str3: %s\n", str3[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Code Example from online:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
int i,j,n;
char str[20][20],temp[20];
puts("Enter the no. of string to be sorted");
scanf("%d",&n);
for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
  gets(str[i]);
for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
  for(j=i+1;j<=n;j++)
  {
       if(strcmp(str[i],str[j])>0)
       {
          strcpy(temp,str[i]);
          strcpy(str[i],str[j]);
          strcpy(str[j],temp);
       }
   }
printf("The sorted string\n");
for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
  puts(str[i]);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not initializing `temp` anywhere. You can't just read and write through a pointer that doesn't point anywhere.

Comment: Same goes for `i`, which you attempt to use as an index without initalizing it first.

Comment: _"I saw one code which do that"_ is of no help to us unless you show us _that exact code_.

Comment: Code updated :) I also edited I indexing. i & j are initialized after main.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Make sure you have warnings enabled *and you heed them*. If you're using GCC, always build with at least `gcc -Wall -Werror`.

Comment: _"i & j are initialized after main"_ You're _declaring_ `i`, but not _initializing_ it. The first time you give `i` a value is at `for(i=0;i<cnt;i++)`.

Comment: Your code is a complete mess. And i is still uninitialized.

Comment: I'm using windows gcc with Dev-C++. Sorry about the initializing, it's m & j. m=0 and j=1. They are the indexing members. The problem is with strcpy(str1[m],str1[j]);

Comment: online code updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is because temp is a pointer and you use it as a string (Char array)
when you call `strcpy(str1[j],temp)`, is where the problem is, i think.

Also notice that the online solution doesnt use *temp pointer, it uses an array

Comment: Problem is not because `temp` is a `char *` pointer , but because of `temp` being not initialized.

Comment: How to initialize it to a string array? I know how to initialize it to int and char.